# How to retrieve the Account of contacts in table format using extension in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I want to display the Account of contacts in a table format using a standard controller and a custom extension in a VisualForce page. Can you please give me an idea of how can I solve this problem?

Comment: One contact can have one account, so how do you want in table format. please clarify your Requirement.

Comment: one account have number of contacts in table format i need  to display the records

Answer (score 1):

This controller and page will help you.

```
public class dataController{
public List<Contact> accLst {get; set;}

public dataController(){
    searchresult();
}


public void searchresult(){
           SYSTEM.DEBUG('Number of records '); 
    accLst = [SELECT Name,lastName,phone,id FROM Contact WHERE name != null LIMIT 999 ];
}


}
```

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accLst}" var="ac">
        <apex:column width="25px">
           </apex:column>
              <apex:column value="{!ac.Name}" headerValue="Name"/>
              <apex:column value="{!ac.LastName}" headerValue="LastName"/>
              <apex:column value="{!ac.phone}" headerValue="Phone"/>
              <apex:column value="{!ac.id}" headerValue="Id"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should build a page like this :

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
   <apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlock title="list" id="contacts_list">
         <apex:pageBlockTable title="contacts List" value="{!contacts}" var="c" width="100%">

              <apex:column value="{!c.FirstName}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!c.LastName}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!c.Email}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!c.AccountId}"/>

         </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
```

This will show you list of contacts and their accounts..In case you want to display a different list you should specify your query..

anyhow your extension class should look something like this :

```
public class ContactExt {

  public Contact currentContact {get; set;}

  public ContactExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
     Id contactId = stdController.getId();

     currentContact = [Select Id, FirstName,LastName,AccountId From Contact Where Id=:contactId AND AccountId!=null];

   }
 }
```

This is an example of Contact Extension Class but you should add a list of account according to your needs...

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page controller="FetchRelatedContact">
    <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:outputText value="Select Account    "/>  <apex:selectList value="{!selVal}" size="1">

           <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllAccount}"/>

       </apex:selectList>
       <br/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Show" action="{!showRelatedContacts}"/>

       <br/>

       <apex:pageBlockTable var="cont" value="{!contacts}">
           <apex:column value="{!cont.name}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!cont.email}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>

       </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

//=======================================

```
public class FetchRelatedContact {

    public list<selectoption> AllAccount { get; set; }
    public list<contact> contacts { get; set; }

    public String selVal { get; set; }

    public FetchRelatedContact(){

        Allaccount = new list<selectoption>();

        list<account> acnts = [select id, name from account];

        for(account ac :acnts){

            allaccount.add(new selectoption(ac.id,ac.name));

        }

    }
    public void showRelatedContacts(){

        contacts = [select name,email from contact where accountid = :selVal];


    }
}
```